# Sorting Elements in Place in Java

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, frequency, comparator

I am trying to sort a list of given elements by decreasing frequency. If two elements have the same frequency, they should appear in increasing order. For example, given the input: `[6, 1000, 3, 3, 1000, 6, 6, 6]` the output should be: `[6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 1000, 1000]`. The elements also must be sorted in place rather than returning a new list.

So far, I have created a HashMap of the key and values, where the key is the element and the value is the frequency. But I'm not quite sure what to do next:

```
public static void method(List<Integer> items)
{
        int size = items.size();
        int count = 0;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            int item = items.get(i);
            if (map.containsKey(item))
            {
                map.put(item, map.get(item) + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(item, 1);
            }
        }
        List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator()
        {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
            {
                return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
                .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
            }
        });
        HashMap sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
        for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the order if two difference frequencies occur the same number of times?

Comment: Don't use raw types. You started off decently and lost somewhere in the middle. Think around this - "You need to *sort the entries* by *value* in *reverse order* and *then by key* for the collisions."

Comment: @WJS I think the problem statement is clearly summarised in the lines *"I am trying to sort a list of given elements by decreasing frequency. If two elements have the same frequency, they should appear in increasing order."* and then the sample output `[6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 1000, 1000]` clarifies it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort inline as follows :

```
public static void sortInline(List<Integer> list) {
    Map<Integer, Long> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                    Collectors.counting())); // frequency map
    Comparator<Integer> frequencyComparison = Comparator
            .<Integer>comparingLong(map::get).reversed(); // sort the entries by value in reverse order 
    list.sort(frequencyComparison.thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())); // then by key for the collisions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void method(List<Integer> list) {
    Map<Integer, Long> map = list.stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                                                Collectors.counting()));
    list.sort(new Comparator<Integer>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
             Long cnt1 = map.get(o1);
             Long cnt2 = map.get(o2);
             int compare = cnt2.compareTo(cnt1);
             if (compare == 0) {
                 return o1.compareTo(o2);
             }
             return compare;
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the line ```map.get(o1)``` and ```map.get(o2)``` -- "long cannot be converted to integer"

Comment: Sorry about that.  I updated the map creation to avoid doing it manually and forgot to update the comparator.